# How to run a single soap request in SoapUI multiple times with different data available in a single property?

Tags: soapui

[Soap Request Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvZAy.png)I have a Soap request which picks up the input value from a property defined in the same Test step. I need to run the same request automatically with multiple data available in the same property file. Is it possible by Get data functionality or do I need to include some scripting for achieving the desired step?The '?' below depict the value which needs t be picked from property.

```
<v1:Reverification>
         <ReverificationRequest>
            <v11:MSISDN>?</v11:MSISDN>
         </ReverificationRequest>
```

[Property file screenshot depicting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBrqO.png)

Comment: What is the structure of the test case? what data do you have in the property?

Comment: It's a Numeric data. A phone number.

Comment: Please post a screen shot if possible. Please reply the answer for other query? Also, you mentioned multiple data which is unclear.

Comment: The screenshot of my request and response alon with the property from where i am picking up the data is included in my original question. Also by multiple data i mean -  There are multiple type of data like Prepaid customer, postpaid customer ect and i need to run the same soap request with all the data present in the property file. i hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: do you have the Pro version (ReadyAPI) ?

Comment: No ,i am using the free version SoapUI where i cannot use datasource as excel. Any other way of doing the same in free version?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a data-driven test.

SoapUI supports the concept of running the same request numerous times by substituting various values in the payload with those in, say, a spreadsheet.

[SoapUi page about data-driven tests](https://www.soapui.org/docs/data-driven-tests/functional-tests.html)

Comment: Is this possible in the free version?

Comment: The Pro version has data-driven test functionality, which is really slick to use.  I do not think it's available in the free version, but you could try reading the link and trying in your version.  There are plenty of posts on SO about 'bending' the free version to run data driven tests.