# Groovy script for hitting the same request with different value for multiple times

Tags: groovy, load-testing

I am new to SOAP UI (using SOAP UI free version). I have a SOAP request XML and I need to run the same request multiple times passing different value for one tag each time. Can anyone please help me with the Groovy script that can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

In SoapUI speak, this is a data-driven test.  SoapUI Pro version has really good support for this, but it is not enabled in the free version.

This is a rather common question on Stack Overflow, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379225/how-to-run-a-single-soap-request-in-soapui-multiple-times-with-different-data-av/48383422#comment97477806_48383422) which also includes a link to a page which describes how you can 'bend' the free version to run data-driven tests.

If you're not tied to SopaUI, you might want to try Postman.  The free version of Postman has data-driven tests out of the box.  See this [link](https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/) from the Postman site about using data files for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sample to do the same.  place all your test condition on local and fetch and run one-by-one

```
    import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder;
    import groovy.io.FileType;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestStepResult.TestStepStatus;
    def  groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );

     // Folder location , where  input files are present, can be change or replace with new location. but same location has to be given here.
     def sInputXMLpath = "C:\\TestFilesFolder\\RequestFiles\\"
     // Test suites name : can be change or replace with new name. but same location has to be given here.
    def sTestSet = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["Demo"]
    //if you have mutliple test cases, please change the index..... it will start with 0..( being first test case )
    def sTestCase = sTestSet.getTestCaseAt(0) 
    log.info "TestCase.name : " + sTestCase.name 
    def iCountTestSteps = sTestCase.getTestStepCount()
    log.info "Total Test Count of Test Steps in your TestSuite : " + iCountTestSteps
    def i = 1 
    new File(sInputXMLpath).eachFile
    {

            def sInputFileName = it.name[0..-1]  
            log.info "Processing the file " + sInputFileName                
            log.info "**********************************************************************" 
            log.info "Test Number_"+ i +"_is Executing"
            log.info "**********************************************************************" 
            log.info "Request of InputFileName : " + sInputFileName + " Is Executing "

            def sTrimName = sInputFileName
            sInputFileName = sTrimName.replaceAll(".xml","")
            sInputFileContent = it.getText('UTF-8')
            sTestCase.getTestStepAt(0).getProperty("Request").setValue(sInputFileContent);

            //log.info "Request content   : " + sTestCase.getTestStepAt(0).getProperty("Request").getValue()
            testRunner.runTestStepByName("TestStepforRequest")
            log.info "Info :TestStepforRequest get Called "

            i++
    }
```